# Loop to check last image in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, random

Thanks to a kind member I found a solution to a code problem of mine! 
But I'm having struggle again with a loop.. I tried to find the solution in answered questions but nothing was working for me..

I want a loop to check if the last image in an array is loaded. I'm making a simple game where you click on a image, and it changes to the next image. The goal is that you have to click multiple times on the image, to get to the last image. If you are at the last image, you win. There needs to be a timer that checks after let's say 5 seconds, if you are at the last image. (I have multiple images that you have to click on, bet I'm showing just one right now)

So I made a for loop like this:

```
  for (eiImg == 'img/ei4.png'){
    alert("yay!");
}
```

It's probably very very wrong but I'm a very amateur programmer so I'm sorry! ;)
Well of course it wasn't working. And I am not even using a timer..

Can someone teach me how to successfully make a loop that checks after 5 seconds if the Image is the last image in the array. I've tried to google it but I just can't find the solution.

Here is my entire javascript code:

```
var eieren = 0;
var eieren = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

var imgArray = [ 'img/ei1.png' , 'img/ei2.png' , 'img/ei3.png', 'img/ei4.png' ];


    imgArray.length;

    var eiImg = imgArray[eieren - 1];

    console.log( eiImg );

// thanks so much for the help Azzy Elvul!
    document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )[0].src = eiImg;
    document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )[0].addEventListener( "click", changeImage ());

    var counter = eieren - 1;

    function changeImage()
    {
        //Load new image if this is not the last image
        if ( counter < imgArray.length - 1 )
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )[0].src = imgArray[ ++counter % imgArray.length];
        }
    };
```

Comment: If you want to check if the image is the last image after 5 second, you can use setTimeout method of javascript. and you can get the last element with array[array.length-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I was curious about this and about the solution you were working on and so I had a go at it myself just to see if I could get it to work. I think my solution is slightly different from your approach. The annotated code is below and there's a JSFiddle demonstration of the code at the end.

```
var imgArray = ['img/ei1.png', 'img/ei2.png', 'img/ei3.png', 'img/ei4.png'];

// get the body element and create an array to keep the image elements
var body = document.querySelector('body');
var imgs = [];

// loop over the list of images, creating new elements
// adding src attributes and click events to them, and then adding
// them to the imgs array we created
for (var i = 0, l = imgArray.length; i < l; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imgArray[i];
    img.addEventListener('click', changeImage);
    imgs.push(img);
}

function changeImage() {

    // are there any image elements left in the img array
    // if there are, continue
    if (imgs.length > 0) {

        // is the length of the img array less than the length
        // of the imgArray - if so, remove the previous image from the page 
        if (imgArray.length !== imgs.length) {
            body.removeChild(document.querySelector('img'));
        }

        // random number based on the number of image elements
        // remaining in the imgs array
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgs.length - 1) + 1);

        // add that image to the body element
        body.appendChild(imgs[random]);

        // remove the image element from the imgs array
        imgs.splice(random, 1);
    }
}

function checkOnLastImage() {

    // are you on the last image?
    if (imgs.length === 0) {
        console.log('congratulations')
    } else {
      console.log('try again');
    }
}

// run changeImage for the first time
changeImage();

// use a setTimeout to check at 5 seconds whether
// the last image has been reached
setTimeout(checkOnLastImage, 5000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/uj6b9w6w/11/)

Comment: Thanks for the help Andy! It's finally working now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check this, its create alert of the last object from the array

```
var imgArray = [ 'img/ei1.png' , 'img/ei2.png' , 'img/ei3.png', 'img/ei4.png' ];
var alertIndex = imgArray.length-1; // the last index from the array
for(var i = 0; i<imgArray.length; i++) {
    if(i == alertIndex) {
        alert(imgArray[i]);
    } 
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egqbLc6v/) - look at this working example.

Answer (score 0):

Why to iterate? Get the last object directly.

```
alert(arr[arr.length-1])
```